# Using an iterator with a linked list in Java

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I have created a linked-list class called "SList", which allows an empty linked-list to be created. The method "insertFront" inserts an object at the front of the list and increases the size. Below, in the main class, I have created an SList object and added two strings to the list. I would like to print this list. I attempted to create an iterator object imported from java.util, but the compiler is giving me a red underline under "Iterator". Why am I getting this error? How should I print this linked-list?

```
public class SList 
{
private SListNode head;
private int size; //number of items in the list

public SList() //constructor, empty list
{
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}
public void insertFront(Object item)
{
    head = new SListNode(item, head);
    size++;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkMain 
  {
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String apples = "apples";
    String oranges = "oranges";

    SList x = new SList();

    x.insertFront(apples);
    x.insertFront(oranges);

    Iterator iter = x.Iterator();






}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your code. Given your current implementation, there is no method that will return an `Iterator` object from your `SList` class.

If you would like to base your implementation off of the Java Collections framework, you should implement the `Collection` interface in your code as such:

```
public class SList<E> implements Collection<E> {
    //override methods here
}
```

The `<E>` is a parameterized type that makes your class type-safe. If you implement the `Collection` interface, you will be required to implement several methods, among them is a method that will return an `Iterator<E>`.

If you choose not to use the Java Collections framework, it is just as easy to do, you'll just need to create all of your own methods.

A great tutorial for generics (if you don't want to use the Collections framework) can be found here [at the Java Tutorials page for generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Another great tutorial for the Collections framework can also be found here [at the Java Tutorials page for Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Have fun!